# AB Test for Total Revenue: How to take both of conversion rate and average order value into account in my ab-test?

Tags: statistical-significance, ab-test

I have some purchase data for two groups of people, for instance:

```
Method     Revenue
A          12
A          0
A          0
A          4  
A          0
B          0
B          8
B          0
B          4  
B          0
```

The purpose of the A/B test is to maximize total revenue.

The problem is with calculating the statistical significance of difference between total revenues of the two groups. Since the distribution of revenues is not normal we cannot use conventional t-test procedure.

Other methods like Wilcoxon ranksums method fail because there are a lot of zeros (99% of data).

We have a large dataset (100K entries) and the total revenue difference between two methods is dramatically high. However, none of the methods proves it is significant.

In other words we are looking for a method to consider both conversion ratio and revenue per paying user for statistical test.

I sincerely appreciate your help.

Comment: For starters, bootstrap this to get a sense of the variability. In addition to that, consider using a smaller sample of probable users, this might offer a more relevant comparison; e.e. a luxury car brand would not just send random e-mails and expect anything other than extremely low conversion rates as most people cannot afford their product anyway.